# DOM tree data structure without XML file

Tags: java, dom, data-structures

I would like to use a DOM XML tree as a data structure, but I don't want to save and read the data into an XML file or a database. Is there an implementation or a library or a framework for Java that allows me?

Also, I wish it were possible to query with XQuery on this tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Document.html

I recommend using the Document class.  You can try creating the Document object with the code below.  From there you can create the hierarchy of elements with its attributes and data as you wish.  You can also query by element name or ID (in lieu of XQuery).  That said, I'm a little confused with your question - DOM is usually HTML specific (HTML being XML), so either way you're using XML.  Good luck in this endeavor.

```
Document d = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
```